# Moving to the next input which was disabled and enabled onchange

Tags: javascript, jquery, focus, readonly, disabled-input

I have a disabled element which I enable it only after value was entered to it's previous input, the problem is that `change` triggers before the input lost focus and the focus moved to the next not disabled element, so removing the `disabled` attribute then is no good.

**HTML:**

```html
Fill this before you continue:      <input id="a" />
Fill this after the previous input: <input id="b" disabled="disabled" />​
```

**jQuery:**

```
$('#a').change(function(){
    if (this.value === "")
        $('#b').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
    else
        $('#b').removeAttr('disabled');
});​
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/swubm/)

I manged to overcome this problem by changing from `disabled` to `readonly` but then it's readonly and not disabled as I preferred, are there **good and robust**(mouse proof) ways to achieve it and using `readonly`?

**Things to consider:**

- Subscribing to multiple events doesn't really seems right.
- The user can paste text to the 1st input without using keyboard at all.

Comment: `change` doesn't  trigger before the input has lost focus AFAIK. What browser are you using?

Comment: @Asad, _"change-
**The change event occurs when a control loses the input focus** and its value has been modified since gaining focus. This event is valid for INPUT, SELECT, and TEXTAREA. element."_ [Spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Events/events.html#Events-eventgroupings-htmlevents)

Comment: just for suggestion: if you are building a form which takes email or password not a raw text then enable the other input when first input was validated successfully! there is no use of method you are using! people will add white-space only and unlock the other input ;)

Comment: Yes, it occurs when the input loses focus, not before.

Comment: In ES5 compatible browsers you can set a `watch` on the value property of the first input, which means regardless of how the value changes the second input's disabled attribute is adjusted appropriately. I can make a demo if you're interested.

Comment: well, what about incompatible? add separate code for them? also detecting the browser whether it supports the watch attribute or not?

Comment: @AspiringAqib There is a polyfill available that adds `watch` support cross browser.

Comment: @Asad, yes I'm really interested.

Comment: @AspiringAqib, I think paste with keyup will work, not with `change`.

Comment: @gdoron Unfortunately, it appears the `value` property doesn't work well with `watch`. It would appear pasting and typing changes some internal property that `value` is a getter for. The best I could come up with is: http://jsfiddle.net/HmzYR/

Comment: well if you wanna add so many events then i should have answered a long ago! i thought my answer will be downvoted because you didn't wanted multiple events!

Comment: @AspiringAqib, you're right, I commented to your comment with `change` + `paste`. please write an answer, I believe this is the best option we have.

Comment: no, man just leave it, i don't wanna add answer! well, it's working as you want?

Comment: @AspiringAqib, yes. I really wish I could delete the question it's a mess!!!

Comment: well, i also think you need to do that :D i will tell truth that when i saw this question, i was laughing that a senior like you is asking this type of question! i know that my recent lines seems odd but that's the truth :D sorry bro well, no need of it, we all downvote your question and it will automatically closed :P

Comment: @AspiringAqib, I wanted a way with one event so if the answer is _you can't..._ there is no purpose in the question... but if there was a way which I and you didn't know... then... I try to stay open minded.

Comment: @gdoron yeah golden lines, well ok wanna remove so you can :D

Comment: @AspiringAqib, after a question got answers only a mod can delete it...

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/22072/discussion-between-aspiring-aqib-and-gdoron)

Comment: @gdoron come in chat wanna ask you some questions ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have said in your question that you don't want to subscribe to multiple events, but this is the only way I can think of to do this. The problem is that different ways of changing the value of the input all interface directly with the C/C++ DOM, but they do not do it through the JS API. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6950650/javascript-watch-event-not-working-on-dom-element-objects) for more on this.

A reasonably bulletproof way of doing it while subscribing to multiple events would be:

```
$('#a').on('keyup paste propertychange input', function() {
    if (this.value === "") $('#b').prop('disabled', true);
    else $('#b').removeAttr('disabled');
});
```

Here is a demonstration: http://jsfiddle.net/HmzYR/

Comment: Thanks, but won't `paste` and `keyup` be enough?

Comment: @gdoron I think Opera has glitches with the paste event. I'll try to find where I read that.

Comment: @gdoron Turns out Opera [doesn't support paste events](http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/events/cutcopypaste.html) at all. The `input` event provides a nice fallback for this.

Comment: And turns out `onpaste` [isn't in the spec at all](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/element.onpaste#Specification).

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered adding an event on `onkeydown` or `onkeyup`?

If the users just needs to enter *something* you can add an event on `onkeyup` that does validation and sets the disabled property of the other input element.

I'm not sure about the order of events but `onkeyup` also fires after the focus has moved I would assume. But this shouldn't be much of problem in this case. One case I can think of is the following sequence of keys: `"a" backspace tab`.
I suppose the perfect solution would be to use `onkeydown` and inspect the key before it's pressed, but it's hard to *predict* the effect of non-readable keys like `backspace` and `arrowdown`.

---

Another suggestion: attach an `onkeydown` listener and look for the `tab` key. Validate the value and enable the next input field.

---

In essence: you either need to catch *all* input events, or all events that change focus (like `tab`). And you must act *before* the events are completed.

Comment: The user can paste text without using keyboard, and subscribing to multiple events doesn't seem right for such a simple task.

Comment: This is not a _simple_ task. You want to do live form generation, that's quite involved. Pasting is not a problem, you will see `ctrl "v" tab`. Validation after `"v"` should enable the next input element.

Comment: well, buddies don't fight and @gdoron please explain what do you exactly want? because i have tried your code and it's working!

Comment: @FritsvanCampen It is possible to paste without using the keyboard.

Comment: @AspiringAqib, I agree this thread became a mass, I wish I could delete it, but I can't do that now...

Comment: i know you don't wanna add multiple events but just a suggestion though ^_^ http://jsfiddle.net/swubm/7/

Answer (score 0):

Use `prop` and not `attr`:

```
$('#b').prop('disabled', true);
```

Also try hooking to the `keyup` event instead of the `change` event.

Here is a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/maniator/swubm/3/

For more explanations please see here: [.prop() vs .attr()](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5874652/561731)

---

Fiddle to handle cutting and pasting using `mouseout`: http://jsfiddle.net/maniator/swubm/4/ (based on comments below)

Comment: You have a typo and anyway I'm almost sure it won't help, but I'll give it a try. **UPDATE:** I tried it at jsFiddle, and it didn't work, not sure why did you think it would.

Comment: @gdoron I added a fiddle demo for you ^_^

Comment: What about the mouse? it seems to be to complicated adding all those events. and the if you subscribe for the `keyup` then the `attr` will work just the same!

Comment: @gdoron what about  the mouse?

Comment: Though it's your question there it doesn't seem like you know the difference between the two.

Comment: @gdoron can you please explain what you mean by mouse?

Comment: Pasting text with mouse doesn't trigger the `keyup` event.

Comment: @gdoron so add `mouseout` if you really want to :-) http://jsfiddle.net/maniator/swubm/4/

Comment: @gdoron you want to do a lot of things. one event is not going to cut it.

Comment: I admit it was I, and I thought I explained why, the `prop` has nothing to do here, so _"this answer is not helpful"_.

Comment: @gdoron umm yes it was. It is not advisable to futz with attributes. Use it's properties and everything will be better and nicer ^_^ also it reduces everything to one line of code ^_^

Answer (score -2):

I updated my answer: http://jsfiddle.net/swubm/10/

```
Fill this before you continue:
<input id="a" />
<br>
<br>
Fill this after the previous input
<input id="b" disabled />​
```

JS:

```
$('#a').bind('input propertychange', function() {
    var value = $('#a').val();
    if (value == "")
        $('#b').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
    else
        $('#b').removeAttr('disabled');

});
```

Comment: If you don't know KO, pls ignore this answer

Comment: @namkha87 Yes. Select something, right click and select copy, go to the input, right click and select paste. Nothing happens to the second input.

Comment: sorry man, I updated my answer. You may have a look. Very easy right :)